# Rxjs Observable + Angular Guard to check if user is logged in

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Setup:** I have a `LoggedInGuard` (injected with `AuthService`). In AuthService's constructor I've subscribed to http.get to set `this.loggedIn = true` based on the response from server.

**Question:** When user is already logged in (another tab or some other time in past) and directly lands on a route (which is `LoggedInGuard` guarded) by the time `http.get` completes, `LoggedInGuard` checks on the this.loggedIn and assumes user is not logged in. How to block the guard until http.get completes ?

Comment: The desired behavior is how guards work by default. Perhaps you have a bug. Did you forget to `return`?

Comment: `canActivate` can return an `Observable<boolean>`, so return one that includes your HTTP request in its composition.

Comment: @cartan oh yeah, but the reason I did **not** use it is: In LoggedInGuard, i have extra logic: if the user is **not** loggedIn, I need to `this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);`